# Как переименовать тему в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

У заказчика сайт на wordpress (сейчас версия 4.2.2) с кастомной темой, которую делали где-то на стороне. Сам движок WP изменениям не подвергался, обновляется встроенными средствами успешно. Внутреннее служебное название темы, похоже, конфликтует с какой-то стандартной темой WP, и админка настойчиво предлагает тему обновить. Тестовое обновление в песочнице всё поломало - в общем, обновляться нельзя.

Как можно переименовать кастомную тему, чтобы WP понял, что она кастомная и не пытался (не предлагал) её обновлять?

Comment: Превые строки в style.css. Переключитесь перед этим на стороннюю тему, чтобы вордпресс внезапно не оказался в ситуации, когда заданной темы нет.

Comment: Название темы в style.css не встречается ни разу, первые строки - CSS код. Никаких комментариев CSS файл не содержит.

Comment: Странно, вордпресс 4+ у меня ругался на отсутствие комментария в style.css. По умолчанию там вся инфа о теме задается ([доки](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC#.D0.A2.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.86.D1.8B_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B9_.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BC.D1.8B))

Comment: А где именно "ругался"? Может и мой ругается, а я не заметил?

Comment: В списке тем не давал вообще переключиться, пока не указал родительскую тему.

Comment: Проверил, не ругается, переключается. Если нажать на "Информация о теме" - показывает только её название и "Автор: Аноним". Может быть Ваш случай связан с "дочерними" темами? Моя тема - полностью кастомная, сделана якобы с нуля, "родительской" у неё не предусмотрено.

Comment: Не могу сейчас точно сказать (и надеюсь, что никогда больше не вернусь к разработке на вордпрессе).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решилась копированием папки с темой в папку с именем, на которое хочется сменить название темы, последующим переключением в админке WP на новую тему и удалении папки с темой исходной. На удивление при этом ничего не сломалось.

Answer (score 2):

в style.css в начале закомментированные строки типа:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Thirteen
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentythirteen/
Author: the WordPress team
Author URI: https://wordpress.org/
*/
```

Если их нет - добавить. Для переименования темы поменять *Theme Name*